Python, pyinstaller: использование splash screen (заставки на старте программы)
В настоящее время командой разработчиков pyinstaller заявлена экспериментальная функция добавления в приложение заставки при загрузке.
Согласно их документации надо сделать вот так:

Добавить в код программы вот это:


в начале import pyi_splash,
а перед основным модулем, когда заставку уже нужно убрать, вот это: pyi_splash.close()


Подготовить нужное изображение.
Добавить в команду сборки вот эту опцию: --splash=path/to/your/splash_image.png

import pyi_splash - не работает! Установить как-то нужный модуль нельзя. Есть ли у кого-нибудь успешный опыт использования такой возможности? Я не исключаю вариант, что это вообще не реализовано до сих пор, такое тоже может быть.

По факту, запускается окно Tkinter, только с кастрированными настройками. Как по мне, проще свою реализацию заставки сделать. В общем, мне не зашло.
import pyi_splash - устанавливать не надо, это уже по умолчанию вшито в pyinstaller (работать будет только после сборки в .exe)
import pyi_splash
import time

pyi_splash.update_text("Привет, моя программа запускается!")
time.sleep(3)

pyi_splash.update_text("Ещё секундочку..")
time.sleep(3)

pyi_splash.close()

Собирал командой:

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --splash "C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/test/13.jpeg"  "C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/test/user.py"

Что бы текст поверх заставки работал (по умолчанию отключен), нужно модифицировать файле .spec, который создает pyinstaller при первом запуске:

Нужно заменить text_pos=None, на координаты позиции, например
text_pos=(10,50),

После этого нужно пересобрать  сборку из файла спецификации - pyinstaller yourFile.spec


Мой .spec если интересно:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/test/user.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
splash = Splash(
    'C:/Users/Amgarak/Desktop/test/13.jpeg',
    binaries=a.binaries,
    datas=a.datas,
    text_pos=(10,50),
    text_size=12,
    minify_script=True,
    always_on_top=True,
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    splash,
    splash.binaries,
    [],
    name='user',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


Вы лично это делали? То есть, Вы утверждаете, что код, который мне предоставили, лично тестировали?
Во-первых, мне этот код уже присылали в качестве примера.
Во вторых, этот Ваш код работает вот так:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\DOWNLOADS\proba.py", line 3, in 
import pyi_splash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyi_splash'
В третьих вот это: import pyi_splash - устанавливать не надо, это уже по умолчанию вшито в pyinstaller. Импорт - это не установка модуля!
У меня Python 3.12.5, pyinstaller 6.10.0. Что-то в попытке запустить Ваш пример идёт не так.

Вот буквально 13 минут назад, специально для вас собрал код из ответа, результат на скриншоте. У меня всё работает и даже текст обновляется на заставке.

Я всё-таки ещё раз спрошу. У Вас в программе отрабатывает команда import pyi_splash? Как Вы её запускаете?

.spec - дело двадцатое. Я хочу понять, каким образом Вы запускаете в работу скрипт, содержащий команду import pyi_splash. Если скрипт выполнится, остальное мелочь.

Запускается только после сборки, а так модуль не найден. Ничего дополнительного не делал. Просто импортировал. Просто запустил команду из ответа выше.

Что и требовалось понять. То есть, я свою программу в режиме .py запустить не смогу? Отладки, костыли... Я плякаль. Руки-крюки в команде pyinstaller написали "экспериментальную функцию"? Ржунимагу. Спасибо, я более в "эксперименте", похоже, не участвую.

Разумеется не сможете, это вшитый модуль в сам pyinstaller.

Вот это обсуждение невозможно без нормального инструментария определений. ВЫ НЕ ИМПОРТИРОВАЛИ! Потому что никакой импорт в программе не работает. Вы добавили команду импорта в программу и сделали сборку. Эта сборка, как Вы утверждаете, работает.  А сам скрипт уже НЕТ.

Если это "это вшитый модуль в сам pyinstaller" какого ж ... я должен добавлять какой-то код импорта ещё и свою программу? Интересно было посмотреть на того писателя-экспериментатора и поспрашивать его.

Если Вам интересно, я достаточно опытный в работе с pyinstaller, меня писанина .spec весьма забавляет. Это лишнее.  Могу дать пример команды вдесятеро короче.

После сборки всё будет работать. От меня то вы чего хотите? Я не разрабатывал сей прикол. И как уже писал в самом ответе, проще самому прикрутить заставку на том же TK или QT где и функциональности по больше и выглядеть будет лучше. А так, могу лишь предложить закоментить\не подключать всё что связано с заставкой от pyinstaller до самой сборки.

Я лайкнул Вам. За труды. Проблема, похоже, исследована. Дурака повалять ради интереса я ещё попробую, есть вариант, но это уже ради исследования. У меня в прогах уже есть режим-debug, есть режим-standalone. Если я не выкручу это сплаш с помощью этого, тема для меня пока закрыта.
